# Named router outlet and lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, router-outlet

I have problem with named router outlet and lazy loading module.
I have 2 router outlets first without name and second is named **mainapp**.

**app.component.html**

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.main.component.html**

```html
<router-outlet name="mainapp"></router-outlet>
```

**app.routes.ts**

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'login',  component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'app', component: AppMainComponent, children:[
        {path: '', loadChildren: 'app/client/client.module#ClientModule'}
    ]}
];
```

**client.module.ts**

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {path: 'client', component: ClientListComponent, outlet: "mainapp" },
      {path: 'client/:id', component: ClientComponent, outlet: "mainapp" }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [ClientListComponent, ClientComponent],
  exports: [ClientListComponent, ClientComponent]
})
export class ClientModule { }
```

1. LoginComponent is loaded into router outlet
2. After login AppMainComponent is loaded into router outlet
3. Now I try load ClientComponent to named router outlet **mainapp**

I get error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'app'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'app
```

When I modified routes to this it works:

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'login',  component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'app', component: AppMainComponent, children:[
        {path: 'client', component: ClientListComponent, outlet: "mainapp" },
        {path: 'client/:id', component: ClientComponent, outlet: "mainapp" }
    ]}
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be known bug that you can follow at:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10981